# Valid URL - Can we add a path after query string in URL

Tags: javascript, web, url, react-router

Is the below a valid URL:
https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url/after-check

If not, what if I want to add some new path after a query string? For example "after-check" here

I've also tried putting a hash after query string to terminate but shall after-check consider as a new pathname?
https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url#/after-check

Answer (score 0):

### First

This is a VALID URL: `https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url/after-check`.

The path is `/news`, and query parameters is

```
{
  "check": "check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url/after-check"
}
```

So I guess this is not the result you want.

### Second

The second URL `https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url#/after-check` is also a valid URL.

The path is `news` and query parameters is `{"check": "check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url"}`. And the part `#/after-check` is HASH but not path.

Comment: Is there a way we can have after-check as a path in the URL? 
Or we can't add path after a query parameter?

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra The path is always before query parameter. Why do you need the path after a query parameter?

Comment: Just some nested path. Suppose after opening a page which requires query param and then after that page we went to another page which is details.
In this case the URL we need is:
https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url/details

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra We usually put the another page URL into query parameters. For  example: `https://www.example.com/news?check=check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url&redirect=${encodeURIComponent(path_to_detail)}`.